# Excel vba runtime error 424

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I would like to create a simple macro, which is something like that:

I have a table with serial numbers and 12 columns measurement result for each serial number. There are a tolerance that has a min. and a max value. I would like to check the results, that if they are in the tolerance field, then set the color of the cell to green.

The table is like this:

[image: screenshot from the tabelle]

and the tolerance values are: `min=250`, `max=450`.

I wrote this code, but something is not correct.

```
Sub turesellenorzes()
Dim i As Integer
i = Selection.Value
If (i >= 250 And i <= 450) Then
Selection.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else: Set Selection.Interior.Color = vbRed
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not using conditional formatting for that? No need to code anything. The error, btw comes from the `set` in the else-branch. In VBA, `set` is only to be used to assign objects

Comment: becasuse i would like to do it with a simple vba code, and to create button for that.

Comment: Oh, i deleted set command, and the code become working. Thanks! :)

Comment: But, this code works only when i select only one cell. How should the code look like if i want to select more than one cell? Using range would be helpful?

Comment: Please try the code i have just posted to check the selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

Select your Range and call `CallTuresellenorzes`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub callturesellenorzes()

Call turesellenorzes(Selection)

End Sub

Sub turesellenorzes(rng As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng

 If cell >= 250 And cell <= 450 Then

 cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen

 Else

 cell.Interior.Color = vbRed

 End If


Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Since then i have solved it in a different way, but yours also working, thanks!

Comment: if you wish to accept my answer, to know everyone that the above code works.